# how to append the results in list?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, nlp

I have CSV file contains reviews and I'm doing some NLP preprocess (tokenizing, stemming ..etc) I only have a problem in the final result. here is my code:

```
def clean_doc(r):
            stop_free = " ".join([i for i in r.lower().split() if i not in stop])
            punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
            normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())
            stemmed = "".join([stemmer.stem(i) for i in normalized])
            return stemmed
##----------------------------------------------------------------------
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 stemmer = PorterStemmer()
 stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
 exclude = set(string.punctuation) 
 lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
 texts = []
 next(data)
 for row in data:
    r = row[1]
    texts.append(clean_doc(r))
 print(texts)
```

the variable **(texts)** doesn't print anything. can anyone tell me where am I wrong?..Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if the final result is actually your only problem, as you say. For example, the WordNetLemmatizer will treat every word as a noun if you don't specify the POS tag. But then, since you apply stemming afterwards, you could skip lemmatisation altogether.

Comment: Does your script actually print nothing? Not even `[]`? If that's the case, then probably the standard output is lost somewhere (ie. an environment problem that has nothing to do with your Python code).

Comment: It doesn't print anything, but when I followed my code from beginning. .I print the (stemmed) and It is printing the results correctly. But I think my problem is when I appended the resul of the function to list (texts) and try to print final result outside the for loop ..it takes very long time and then when it finished there is no data appeared..just empty space

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where the script shown would print nothing, not even an empty pair of brackets, nor any error message. I'm afraid I can't help you.